# Confused about why index is not being used

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

When I run the following query with `explain`:

```
explain 
SELECT `leads`.* 
FROM `leads` 
  INNER JOIN `people` ON `people`.`id` = `leads`.`person_id` 
WHERE `people`.`email` = 'email@test.co.za'
```

I get:

```
+----+-------------+--------+-------+-------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type  | possible_keys                 | key                   | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+-------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | people | const | PRIMARY,index_people_on_email | index_people_on_email | 768     | const |    1 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | leads  | ref   | fk_person_lead                | fk_person_lead        | 5       | const |    2 | NULL        |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+-------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
```

I understand that `index_people_on_email` is used since the search is on email and there is an index on email. Also no other columns are referenced in the people table.

I am guessing the reason the index is not being used on lead is due to the fact that I am pulling more data from the leads table `leads.*` than is on `fk_person_lead`.

What's confusing me is I thought I the query would still use the foreign key reference to filter the leads and then do lookups to get the rest of the information.

What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: What index is not being used? As I understand, two indexes are being used: `index_people_on_email` (on table `people`) and `fk_person_lead` (on table `leads`). What's the problem with that?

Comment: The column extra says using index for `index_people_on_email`, but it does not say that for `fk_person_lead`. Does that not mean the fk_person_lead index is not being used?

Comment: AFAIK an empty or null extra doesnt mean anything,an index is used if it appears in the key column.Extra offers additional info such as if the index only is used or if it also need to touch the table.

Comment: @abl I think you are both correct. Using a larger data set gave extra information 'using where' for `fk_person_lead`. And what @Mihai makes sense. So it was being used all along.

Comment: "no other columns are referenced in the people table" --> "Using index", which is faster than not having it.  'key' and 'key_len' imply that the index _is_ used.  It looks like `person_id` is `NULLable`; is that deliberate?